# RNDocumentPicker: Native module is not available

Tags: javascript, react-native

I followed the directions exactly as described here (https://github.com/Elyx0/react-native-document-picker/issues/94?fbclid=IwAR2Ke7ejhPYaJcT0bS7jTZHbZvXM570C7aHQQRAvHQz56C9qzvf3W1R5SkA) but it's not working. I get this error:

```
RNDocumentPicker: Native module is not available, make sure you have finished the installation process and rebuilt your app


Error: not opened
at WebSocket.send (/Users/miajohansson/Desktop/bnook/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:219:16)
at send (/Users/miajohansson/Desktop/bnook/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/util/webSocketProxy.js:26:12)
at WebSocket.debuggerSocket.onmessage (/Users/miajohansson/Desktop/bnook/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/util/webSocketProxy.js:48:48)
at WebSocket.onMessage (/Users/miajohansson/Desktop/bnook/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:442:14)
at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:214:7)
at Receiver.ontext (/Users/miajohansson/Desktop/bnook/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:841:10)
at /Users/miajohansson/Desktop/bnook/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:536:18
at /Users/miajohansson/Desktop/bnook/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:368:7
at /Users/miajohansson/Desktop/bnook/node_modules/ws/lib/PerMessageDeflate.js:249:5
```

When I add DocumentPicker in my code (below), I get a TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of defined.

```
import { DocumentPicker, DocumentPickerUtil } from 'react-native-document-picker';

// iPhone/Android
DocumentPicker.show({
      filetype: [DocumentPickerUtil.images()],
    },(error,res) => {
      // Android
      console.log(
         res.uri,
         res.type, // mime type
         res.fileName,
         res.fileSize
      );
    });
```

I've deleted node_modules and run npm install but I still get this error.

Answer (score 1):

Please in which installation you are, npm or yarn, the installation wasn't complete. Try to redo `yarn add react-native-document-picker --save` or `npm install react-native-document-picker --save`.

Answer (score 0):

All errors of sort Native module is not available, has to be solved by updating pods and rebuilding the app